# how to remove a specific item from an array based on what item you click using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to click on a list item(which is made from the items of the array) and remove it permanently from the array. I am able to remove it when clicked using remove(), but when I add another item to the array the item shows back, plus the new item i just added.

JSFIDDLE account: http://jsfiddle.net/trav5567/3s64o1ta/1/

Javascript

```
      function testArray(){
       var Fruit = ['apple', 'bannanna', 'rasberry', 'watermelon', 'grape', 'orange'];
       function initArray(){
        loopArray();
       }initArray();
       function myFruit(){
         $('#addFruit').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var flag = true;
          var val = $('#fruitAdd').val();
          for(var i = 0 ; i < Fruit.length ; i ++){
            if(Fruit[i] == val){
              flag = false;
              console.log('already entered this item');
             }        
           }
           if(flag){
            Fruit.push(val);
            loopArray();
           }
         });
         }myFruit();
         function loopArray(){
           var fruitList = $('ul.fruit');
           var arrayContainer = $('.arrayContainer');
           fruitList.empty();
           for(var i = 0; i< Fruit.length; i++){
             fruitList.append('<li>'+Fruit[i]+'</li>');
           }
          }
         function removeItem(){
            var itemClicked = $('ul.fruit li');
            itemClicked.on('click', function(){
               $(this).remove();
            });
         }removeItem();
       }testArray();
```

Comment: when you are using jquery add `jquery` tag to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing item from array when clicked, you are just removing the li tag which contains element when clicked, for to remove element from array also when clicked on item's li, you have to use splice method to remove element from array as

```
    var itemClicked = $('ul.fruit li');
       itemClicked.on('click', function () {
       $(this).remove();
       var item = $(this).text();
       var index = Fruit.indexOf(item);
      Fruit.splice(index,1);
   });
```

[**Check the Working Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/chakravarthysm/yvru3a2e/)

Comment: what does the 1 stand for next to index? (index,1)? I realized i can put any number in their and it still works...

Comment: 1 stands for number of items to be removed from array from index(which is passed as first argument) position

Comment: i noticed that after i remove an item and then add another item i am unable to remove any more items??

Comment: Is their a way to fix this so that after i remove an item and then add an item back to the array that i can then delete an item again?

Comment: I have fixed it, you can check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chakravarthysm/yvru3a2e/1/, you have to just bind ul for click event passing li and repeat the same in callback as in itemclicked event callback